# Unable to use Viewbag List Items in Razor foreach loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an Images table linked to an Item table (one Item can have many Images). They are linked by the Item Id.

I want to return all images for an Item on the details page. I have been trying to use  a Viewbag to achieve this (below).

Controller:

```
ViewBag.imageFile = (from f in storeDB.Images
                               where f.ItemId == id
                               select f.ImageURL).ToList();
```

View:

```
@foreach (var image in ((List<string>)ViewBag.imageFile)) 
{
    @ViewBag.imageFile    
}
```

The above will return 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]' for each ImageUrl.
I believe the issue is that an object is being return rather than the actual List item string value but cannot figure out how to convert it to the string I need. The plan is to edit this foreach to create an img link for each URL.

I also have the following Viewbag (testing to see I was able to get the Urls at least):

```
ViewBag.imageURL = string.Join(",", ViewBag.imageFile);
```

The above returns the correct URLs but they are all in one string separated by a comma.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Inside the loop in the view, you should use the loop variable:

```
@foreach (var image in ((List<string>)ViewBag.imageFile)) 
{
    @image
}
```

`ViewBag.imageFile` is the complete list and will always be, even inside the loop. The `image` loop variable will be the current item from the list on every turn of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

`ViewBag` does not require a type casting:

```
@foreach (var image in ViewBag.imageFile)) 
    {
        @image
    }
```